# Combinatorics without repetition with order, limits and duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

I'm new here, and I came across a problem that probably has already been answered before, but I couldn't find it.

I have $n$ types of balls with different quantities, with $a_1$ balls of type 1, $a_2$ balls of type 2, and so on. How many different ways are there to arrange $K$ balls in a row, where $K < n$?

Comment: Is $k=\Sigma{a_i}$ ?

Comment: it not the case, I update the question

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: See also the linked questions at that answer for more information.